# Get WordPress Post ID from Post title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue with a custom WordPress theme I'm developing. It's a bit convoluted, but essentially, what I need to do is get a Post Id by it's Post Title. In pseudo-code it would ideally be something like:

```
title = "foo";
post_id = get_post_id_where_title_is(title);
```

The title mentioned is a static reference not being pulled in from WordPress, it's already present on the page.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Just a quick note for anyone who stumbles across this:
[get_page_by_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) can now handle any post type.
The `$post_type` parameter has been added in WP 3.0.

Comment: +1 always better to use a core function than some arbitrary mySQL query.

Comment: The function name is confusing, though.

Comment: get_page_by_title is now deprecated

Answer (score 19):

Found a solution if anyone else struggles with this. Only posted the question out of desperation after 4 hours testing/Googling!

```
function get_post_by_title($page_title, $output = OBJECT) {
    global $wpdb;
        $post = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type='post'", $page_title ));
        if ( $post )
            return get_post($post, $output);

    return null;
}
```

Found at: http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/2009/09/18/retrieving-posts-and-pages-based-on-title-in-wordpress.html

Comment: Just put that function in your functions.php file.

Comment: Note that you may wish to change post_type to 'page' if you want to get the id for a page.  You can also omit the post_type from the SQL where clause to search all revisions, pages, and posts, etc.  (All types in other words.)

Comment: I suspect this could return draft/trashed versions, since it doesn't have the criteria `status='published'`....

Answer (score 9):

Like Michal Mau mentioned:

Use

```
$my_post = get_page_by_title( 'My Title', OBJECT, 'post' );
echo $my_post->post_content;
```

It's `( $page_title, $output, $post_type )` to easily receive a post instead of a page.

Comment: get_page_by_title is now deprecated

Comment: @ChrisPink Thank you. More intel here : https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/03/06/get_page_by_title-deprecated/

Answer (score 2):

May this will help you more by creating function so that you need not to repeat the code

```
function get_page_id_by_title($title)
{
$page = get_page_by_title($title);
return $page->ID;
}

$title = "your title";
get_page_id_by_title($title);
```

Comment: get_page_by_title is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code as per [a link][http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title][1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) )!

```
<?php 
$page = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
wp_list_pages( 'exclude=' . $page->ID );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) differ **post_title** and **post_name** from each other. post_name maybe is the slug. post_title is the title of post.

2)

```
$titlee = "yourtitle";
echo $id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts WHERE post_name = $titlee");
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

Another way to get the post and page ID, is to use a plugin..

there is a plugin, that what it simply does, is just add a column to your all pages, all posts, all categories tables, and have a column title of ID...and right below, you will see all the page/post id listed in that column..

I think that should be very useful..

I use this plugin very frequently and it is very lightweight.

http://getyourblogready.com/?p=758

Comment: Posting code would be more useful for us to get an idea of what you're proposing...

Answer (score -1):

No need to use any type of SQL querys or plugin, use Wordpress standard functions for this

```
$page = get_page_by_title( 'Home' );
$page_id = $page->ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

it is easy to get the post id from post title using wp query:

```
global $wpdb;

$rw = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("select * from "your post table name" where post_title='your variable name or your post title'"));

echo $rw->ID;
```