# Wordpress query_posts by title instead of page_id?

Tags: wordpress, title

Let's say the page i'm displaying has the title "About" and the id is 49. Is there a way to change it so it pulls the pages title instead of the id.

At the moment the code I am using is as follows:

```
<?php
    query_posts('page_id=49');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content();
    endwhile;
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Seems an odd request to have.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wish to get / display the post's content by only supplying the post's `title` instead of an `id`?

Comment: I'm turning my website into a wordpress theme. It is a single page scrolling portfolio, so all the pages (About, Portfolio, Contact) are displayed on the one page. At the moment I have it displaying the pages by their ID, but I thought it would be easier if it used their title instead. Mainly because the titles of these pages will never change they are static, but if the ID changes it will require minor changes to the code.

Comment: @John: I've used something similar before, see -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245861/wordpress-query-posts-by-title-instead-of-page-id/7246236#7246236

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used something similar on a project, using the post's `slug`; save this in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_content_by_slug' ) ) :
/**
 * Get content using a slug
 *
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */    
function get_content_by_slug($page_slug) {
    $page = get_page_by_path($page_slug);
    if ($page) {
        $page_content = $page->post_content;
        $page_content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_content);            
        return $page_content;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
endif;
```

**Usage:**

```
<?php echo get_content_by_slug('page-slug'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. One small problem however. It is displaying my "About" page, but for some reason the default Hello World post is appearing below. It is only post that exists on my blog at the moment, as all the secions are Pages.

Comment: @John: Possibly because you're running it within [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)...

Comment: Hi i'm not very good at this, I added the code I'm trying to use to the end of the original question, am I doing it right? Cheers!

Comment: @John: If you remove the code after `get_content_by_slug` function, i.e. the `while (have_posts()) : the_post();` and the rest of it until `endwhile;`, it won't show the other post(s).

Answer (score 3):

[Get WordPress Post ID from Post title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536682/get-wordpress-post-id-from-post-title)

Found this for you. You want to be careful however, because titles from posts and pages can change. I'm sure you have your reasons.

### EDIT

This may be better actually... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title